# Where is Privacy to config Chromecast to development

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cast, chromecast

On "Get started" topic of chromecast site to config my Chromecast to development, says: "Under Privacy, check the box to Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates.
You must select this option in order to enable your receiver device for development."

But I don't can to find this option, I'm using chrome extension.

Comment: I needed to use the app for android, with chrome extension it's not possible!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you have to use the Chromecast Setup App (not the extension).  It is available here: https://cast.google.com/chromecast/setup.

Comment: I'm using Mac, but I was used the Setup App, but I don't found this option, but with Android App I got!! But anyway, thanks for answer!!